# Are there any math journals or magazines with math problems for middle school or university?

Tags: journals

Are there any math journals or magazines with math problems for middle school or university ?

Comment: Look for the magazines and journals published by the NCTM or the MAA.

Comment: I think you should indicate the ages you are interested in targeting. When you say "middle school or university", to me this means "ages 11-14 or ages 18-22", leaving me to wonder why you are omitting ages 15-17.

Answer (score 5):

The various journals listed in the MSE question [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/129326/) can help with the university portion. These include, but are not limited to, the journals:

- The American Mathematical Monthly (AMM)
- College Mathematics Journal (CMJ)
- Mathematics Magazine
- Math Horizons (I especially like this journal)

The MSE link above contains descriptions of each; I would say that the AMM problems are generally quite difficult, and/but the Math Horizons problems could be fun to try at a variety of math st/ages.

As mentioned in a comment, there are also some NCTM journals. Previously, there were three different journals that covered up through [something like] the second year of college; but, all of those journals have since been combined to form a single publication that launches in January 2020:

- [**Mathematics Teacher: Learning and Teaching PK-12 (MTLT)**](https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Mathematics-Teacher_-Learning-and-Teaching-PK-12/)

I assume that this journal will contain problems, as its predecessors all did; to this end, you may wish to check back issues of NCTM's:

- Mathematics Teaching in Middle School (MTMS)
- The Mathematics Teacher (MT)

Each of these has, at the least, a set of calendar problems. You can also find a good number of articles around problems; for example, I contributed a selection of problems in an article for MT about roots of polynomials ([**link without paywall**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318100979)).

Finally, although it is not a journal or magazine, if you are simply interested in problems, then there are lots of resources online. One possibility - since your original question mentions middle school - is to look at past competitions from MathCounts; you can find their problems archived [**here**](https://www.mathcounts.org/programs/competition-series/past-competitions). At the other end of the spectrum, you can find very challenging problems in the archive of Putnam Problems maintained [**here**](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/). Both of these linked sites also contain sample solutions.

Comment: Another lovely collection of problems can be found at the Julia Robinson Math Festival site: https://www.jrmf.org/activities/

Comment: To @SueVanHattum 's suggestion, maybe it is worth pointing back to the earlier and relevant [**MESE 7394**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7394) in case the OP is curious more generally about sources for problems.